# How to add background shapes to text in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers, background

I am not a designer I just need to learn very simple things, that will make my life easier, how to add this shape and background to text just like the attached photos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried, or what has failed?

Comment: I didn't try, I need to learn how to make it.

Comment: These are very basic compositions using layers. You should try some basic/beginner tutorials about using layers in Photoshop or Illustrator. There are lots on youtube.

Comment: I watched a lot but couldn't find what I want, can you share with me a video that helps me

Comment: Try this one: [Layers for Beginners Photoshop CC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gxcIn8L__w)

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

This is, overall, basic **[layer](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/ps-layers-basics.html)** construction....

Use the **[shape tools](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-shapes.html)** to add shapes on a layer above a photograph.

Then add **[text](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/add-edit-text.html)** to a layer *above* the shape you drew.

[image]

The blue links are for Adobe's help sections for Photoshop regarding these features. If you are unfamiliar with how to do any of these steps, please click the links and review how the features operate.

---

In Illustrator, construction is essentially the same but the toolsets are different. You don't need new *layers* in Illustrator. The objects will simply stack on top of one another. However, since the basis of the entire image is a raster photograph, this type of stand-alone image is generally best accomplished in Photoshop.